# How can I draw both line and point by ggplot according to one variable (R)？

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw the "measured"with point, and the "simulated"with line, but I don't know how to select or subset under ggplot. Could anyone help me please? Thank you!

[x-Date,y-SWC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1MKZ.png)[Current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AS6p.png)[Current graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb1Ii.png)

```
library(foreign)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(scales)
X0_40cm <- read_excel("C:/Rstudy/For_0-40cm.xlsx")
View(X0_40cm)
gg <- ggplot(X0_40cm,aes(Date,SWC))+
  geom_point(aes(col=Condition))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,0.4),labels=percent) +
  labs(title="Soil water content (0-40cm)",y="Soil water content",x="Date")+
  theme_update(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))
gg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to include your `X0_40cm` data using `dput()` instead of an image.

One quicker way to subset for purposes of plotting is to specifically include `data=subset...` for both `geom_point` and `geom_line`.

Also note to include `group=1` in your aesthetic since you want a line plotted.

```
ggplot(X0_40cm, aes(Date,SWC,group=1))+
  geom_point(data=subset(X0_40cm, Condition=="Measured"))+
  geom_line(data=subset(X0_40cm, Condition=="Simulated"))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,0.4),labels=percent) +
  labs(title="Soil water content (0-40cm)",y="Soil water content",x="Date")+
  theme_update(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so so so much!!!!!!! I feel like I can graduate in time now!

Comment: I did:) Thank you again!